# clone a div and insertAfter last child of siblings within relative parents

Tags: javascript, jquery

My markup like this:--

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <button type="button">press</button>
</div>
.
.
.
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="z"></div>
   <button type="button">press</button>
</div>
```

I want when I click the button it clone only one closest siblings and insert the clone div after the last siblings within relative parent div.wrap. I know how to clone with jQuery but I couldn't insert the cloned div after last siblings within relative parent .

Comment: So if I click the first button in your example above, what should be the result?

Comment: if I click the button <div class="a"></div>  will be cloned and added after last <div class="a"></div> within it parent wrap div.Similarly If I click <div class="z"></div> it'll clone and added after last <div class="z"></div> within it's parent wrap div.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.before()` to insert before the button and `.prev()` to clone the div above the button:

```
$('.wrap > button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).before( $(this).prev().clone() );
});
```

```js
$('.wrap > button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).before( $(this).prev().clone() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="a">A1</div>
    <div class="a">A2</div>
    <button type="button">press</button>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
   <div class="z">Z1</div>
   <button type="button">press</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should be able to use [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to find the previous div, then append a clone using [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/).

```js
$(".wrap button").click(function() {
  var prev = $(this).prev("div");
  prev.after(prev.clone());
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 5px;
}

.a {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.z {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <button type="button">press</button>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="z"></div>
   <button type="button">press</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if i correctly understood problem

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  var siblings = $(this).siblings();
  siblings.last().clone().insertAfter(siblings.last() )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="a">a1</div>
    <div class="a">a2</div>
    <button type="button">press</button>
</div>
.
.
.
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="z">z1</div>
   <button type="button">press</button>
</div>
```